# How to find the percentile for each observation in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

Suppose we have a simple data frame:

```
structure(c(2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 67, 8, 11), dim = c(6L, 
2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("lo", "li")))
```

How can I find the percentile for each observation for both variables?

Comment: *"the percentile"*, which one? There are 101 if we stick with the integers. *"data frame"*: this is a `matrix` not a `data.frame`. What is your expected output, a `list`, a `matrix`, a `vector`, or a `data.frame`? (You tagged [tag:dplyr] so I'm inferring a frame, but ... need to make sure.)

Comment: I would like to have a data frame. One column to be lo, one column the percentile (or quantile) for each observation of lo, la and one column the percentile (or quantile) for each observation of la. So four columns n total, two are the original and two contain percentiles (or quantiles) of the original variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most R friendly approach would be to (i) convert this to a dataframe (or tibble), (ii) reshape the data into long format, (iii) groupby lo and li, and (iv) calculate the percent rank.

Here's the code:

```
df%>%
  as_tibble() %>% # convert to dataframe
  gather(key=variable,value=value) %>% # gather into long form
  group_by(variable)%>%. # group by lo and li
  mutate(percentile=percent_rank(val)*100) # make new column

variable   val percentile
   <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 lo           2         20
 2 lo           4         40
 3 lo           5         60
 4 lo           6         80
 5 lo           8        100
 6 lo           1          0
 7 li           2          0
 8 li           4         20
 9 li           6         40
10 li          67        100
11 li           8         60
12 li          11         80
```

If you don't want to make the dataframe long, just do the two columns seperately:

```
df%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(lo_pr=percent_rank(lo)*100)%>%
  mutate(li_percentile=percent_rank(li)*100)


lo    li lo_pr li_percentile
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1     2     2    20             0
2     4     4    40            20
3     5     6    60            40
4     6    67    80           100
5     8     8   100            60
6     1    11     0            80
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` approach to get the median, 5- and 95% quantiles.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data = structure(c(2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 67, 8, 11), dim = c(6L, 
                                                           2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("lo", "li")))

data %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% # Coerce to dataframe
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%  # Pivot to long format
  group_by(name) %>% # For each unique group..
  summarise(perc5 = quantile(value, 0.05), # Calculate 5% quantile
            median = median(value), # Calculate median
            perc95 = quantile(value, 0.95)) # Calculate 95% quantile

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   name  perc5 median perc95
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 li     2.5     7     53  
#> 2 lo     1.25    4.5    7.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**data.table solution**

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(data)

q <- c(0.05, 0.95)

melt(data, measure.vars = names(data))[, setNames(as.list(quantile(value, q)), paste("q", q * 100, sep = "_")), variable]
```

**results**

```
variable  q_5 q_95
1:       lo 1.25  7.5
2:       li 2.50 53.0
```

**data**

```
data = structure(
  c(2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 67, 8, 11),
  dim = c(6L, 2L), 
  dimnames = list(NULL, c("lo", "li"))
)
```